# nette router: match and RouteList

Tags: nette

I'm trying to map pages from database to root of domain:

**now I have have**

```
/posts/post1-url
/posts/post2-url/slashed
```

**I want**

```
/post1-url
/post2-url/slashed
```

How can I make router that **matches the strings above with db**, and if not matched, continues matching routeList like below?

```
<?php
public static function createRouter(): RouteList
    {
        $router = new RouteList;
        $router->addRoute('/', 'Home:default');
        $router->addRoute('/auth', 'Auth:default');
        $router->addRoute('/auth/<action>', 'Auth:<action>');
        $router->addRoute('/admin', 'Admin:default');
        $router->addRoute('/admin[/<action>][/<slug>]', 'Admin:<action>');
        $router->addRoute('/<slug>', 'Home:viewPage');
        $router->addRoute('<presenter>/<action>', '<presenter>:<action>');
        return $router;
    }
```

I have presenter action that can process showing the database post, but found no way to match route list in action, or other way to combine the match+routeList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this approach.

*BlogRouter.php*

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Router;

use Nette\Http\IRequest;
use Nette\Http\UrlScript;
use Nette\Routing\Router;
use Nette\Utils\Strings;

final class BlogRouter implements Router
{
    private const Posts = [
        'first-page',
        'second/page',
    ];

    public function match(IRequest $httpRequest): ?array
    {
        $slug = Strings::trim($httpRequest->getUrl()->getPath(), '/');

        if (in_array($slug, self::Posts)) {
            return [
                'presenter' => 'Blog',
                'action' => 'post',
                'slug' => $slug,
            ];
        }

        return null;
    }

    public function constructUrl(array $params, UrlScript $refUrl): ?string
    {
        if (!array_key_exists('slug', $params) || !in_array($params['slug'], self::Posts)) {
            return null;
        }

        return $refUrl->getHostUrl() . '/' . $params['slug'] . '/';
    }
}
```

*RouterFactory.php*

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Router;

use Nette\Application\Routers\RouteList;
use Nette\Routing\Router;
use Nette\StaticClass;

final class RouterFactory
{
    use StaticClass;

    public static function createRouter(): RouteList
    {
        $router = new RouteList;

        $router->add(new BlogRouter());
        $router->addRoute('/<slug [0-9a-z-]+>/', 'Page:default');
        $router->addRoute('/', 'Homepage:default');

        return $router;
    }
}
```

You can simply update BlogRouter code to use database. But you should cache uris, not query them on each request.

Comment: thank you, so i can use BlogRouter along with another RouterFactory and add it to routes. Thats the part i missed before, thank you very much